# egor khmele's jQuery UI Slider plugin different left and right handle color

Tags: jquery, plugins, slider

I am using a jQuery plugin from here:

http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/

How can I make the left and right handle different colors?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphics (or sprites) for these handles/pointers are contained within an image called
`jslider.plastic.png`. Here's how it looks: http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/img/jslider.plastic.png

If you create a new image based on `jslider.plastic.png` but where you make everything red, and name that image "jslider.plastic.red.png" you can then modify the CSS class that is being applied to the right handle like this:

```
.pointer-to
{
  url(../img/jslider.plastic.red.png); 
}
```

Now you will have a blue left handle and a red right handle.

-

Another option would be to extend the sprite image `jslider.plastic.png` with the red versions of the handles. Just add them to the right of the existing blue handles (you see two versions, those represent a non-pressed and a pressed state respectively). And then you will need to alter your css for .pointer-to to look something like this:

```
.pointer-to
{
     background-position: -40px -40px; // x, y
}
```

You might have to play with the x-coordinate to get it to align with the image.
This way you will reduce the number of sprite images that needs to be requested by the browser. It's a good thing to merge these sprite images if you know that you are always going request and use both of them together.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly after I got my selectors correct.